# Не работает пагинация в WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Пишу в шаблоне категорий такой код:

```
$temp = $wp_query;
        $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $wp_query = null;
        $cat_posts_count = 5;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query( array
            (
                'posts_per_page'    => $cat_posts_count,
                'offset'          =>  $paged == 1 ? 0 : ($paged - 1) * $cat_posts_count,
                'orderby'         => 'post_date',
                'order'           => 'DESC',
                'include'         => '',
                'exclude'         => '',
                'meta_key'        => '',
                'meta_value'      => '',
                'paged'             => $paged,
                'post_type'       => 'product',
                'post_mime_type'  => '',
                'post_parent'     => '',
                'post_status'     => 'publish',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field'    => 'id',
                        'terms'    => $cat_id
                    )
                )
            ) );

         while( $wp_query->have_posts() )
        {
            $wp_query->the_post();
            echo '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 wr_card">';
                ss_get_content_product($post);
            echo '</div>'; 
        }
the_posts_pagination($args);
$wp_query = $temp;
```

Первая страница нормально выводится, вторая уже не выводится.

Проблему понимаю. Пагинация работает на уровне основного запроса и так как осн. запрос выплевывает все записи, то и второй страницы он не видит, так как думает, что уже все отобразил.

Перезаписал осн. запрос, а он все равно не работает.

Comment: а как вы переписали основной запрос? приведите пример кода

Comment: В принципе он в вопросе приведен. Примерно так: `$temp = $wp_query;
        $wp_query = null;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );`. Конечно могу ошибаться. Выслушаю любой конструктив.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в начале `global $wp_query;`, это же глобальная переменная. Хотя, честно говоря, не приходилось видеть чтобы таким образом переписывали основной запрос :)

Comment: Как вы перезаписываете основной запрос?

Comment: Вообще, перезаписывать основной запрос не следует. Но если уж пришлось, то можно использовать функцию [wp()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp/), которая основной запрос и устанавливает. А лучше вмешаться в текущий запрос с помощью хука `pre_get_posts`, это событие срабатывает до отправки запроса в БД, поэтому в него можно добавить какие-то свои параметры

Comment: Хук `pre_get_posts` знаю. Но лучше использовать хук `request`. Он вешается только на основной запрос, а `pre_get_posts` вешается на все запросы. Из-за этого может получиться билиберда если на странице много запросов.

Comment: `$query->is_main_query()` решает проблему разных запросов. А так-то на вкус и цвет, как известно. Для меня предпочтительнее `pre_get_posts` потому, что он вызывается после `request`. Последний не стала упоминать, т. к. вижу, что его вы уже и сами нашли

Comment: Я просто хотел подчеркнуть, что request и pre_get_posts по разному работают.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос добавлением хука в файл function.php

```
function my_request( $request ) {
    $dummy_query = new WP_Query();
    $dummy_query->parse_query( $request );

    if ( $dummy_query->is_archive() ) {
        $request['posts_per_page'] = 1;
    }

    return $request;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'my_request' );
```

Answer (score -2):

Не забываем, что есть ещё страница с поиском. Можно добавить

```
function my_request( $request ) {
    $dummy_query = new WP_Query();
    $dummy_query->parse_query( $request );

    if ( $dummy_query->is_archive() ) {
        $request['posts_per_page'] = 1;
    }
    elseif ( $dummy_query->is_search() ) {
        $request['posts_per_page'] = 1;
    } 

    return $request;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'my_request' );
```

Comment: Про страницу с поиском вроде в вопросе речь не идёт. Что вы имели в виду?